# Install specific version of python2 with homebrew

Tags: macos, python-2.7, homebrew

I've installed python 2.7.13 with homebrew but I need 2.7.10. It seems something trivial... I've seen similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705818/1345165) but I haven't been able to install it.

I've tried to tap `homebrew/versions` and then do `brew search python` but there are no versions (rather than python2 and python3).

Answer (score 16):

Homebrew doesn't do this, I would recommend using homebrew to install [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) and then using pyenv to install and use python 2.7.10, and any other versions you need.

**Get pyenv:**

```
brew update
brew install pyenv
```

Then add `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` to your `.bash_profile` and relaunch terminal.

**Install python 2.7.10:**

```
pyenv install 2.7.10
```

You can then set 2.7.10 as the global python by using `pyenv global 2.7.10` but I would instead recommend you look at the [pyenv virtualenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv) or [pyenv virtualenvwrapper](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenvwrapper) projects and use a python virtual environment for your code, or set the python for your project folder only by `cd`'ing to your project folder and using `pyenv local 2.7.10`.

Comment: For me even after installing pyenv it says: pyenv: command not found, Any pointers?

Comment: @Sid were there any errors installing with homebrew? It should put pyenv on your path as `/usr/local/bin/pyenv`