# Install python@2 on a Mac after python 2 support has ended on Homebrew

Tags: python, python-2.7, github, python-2.x, deprecated

I would like to install a few packages from a github project and one of the dependencies is `python@2`.

Prior to Jan 1 2020, it was possible to install `python@2` using Homebrew:

```
$ brew install python@2
```

However, Python 2 support has ended from Homebrew. Is there anyway to install `python@2` on a Mac now that Python 2 support has ended?

Until the code in this project is ported to Python 3, unfortunately I'm stuck with getting it to work with Python 2 (and dependencies which use Python 2), which is the reason I would like to install `python@2` as a temporary solution.

Comment: I know that on linuux I would download and build from sources. But I don't know if this possible on mac.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MacOS: How to downgrade homebrew Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44217507/macos-how-to-downgrade-homebrew-python)

Comment: @PavelVergeev Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately I'm not able to install `pyenv` on Catalina. The other issue is actually being able to find the source for `python@2`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to find the exact same question -- [Brew - reinstalling python@2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60298514/brew-reinstalling-python2). Unfortunately I can't raise the duplicate flag again so I'll duplicate the answer:

```sh
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/86a44a0a552c673a05f11018459c9f5faae3becc/Formula/python@2.rb
```

Comment: This answer no longer works.  A working option one can found in this answer...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63844926/mac-install-python3-6-with-brew

Comment: Error: Installation of python@2 from a GitHub commit URL is unsupported! `brew extract python@2` to a stable tap on GitHub instead.